# Ini files update using perl

Tags: perl, ini

How can I update the value of the parameter in an ini file without modifying anything else?
Currently I am using setVal() as shown below, but this deletes a parameter when it updates the other parameter value.

```
sub setVal
{
   my $section = shift;
   my $parameter = shift;
   my $value = shift;

   my $ini_path = "C:\\MyFolder\\Ini.ini";
   my $inicfg = Config::IniFiles->new( -file => $ini_path );

   $inicfg -> setval($section,$parameter,$value);
   $inicfg -> WriteConfig($ini_path);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you used?

Comment: We can't (usually) guess what the problem is without seeing code.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work as I expect.

```
$ cat my.ini
[section]
name=dave
foo=bar

[another section]
stuff=random

$ cat changeini 
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Config::IniFiles;

my $cfg = Config::IniFiles->new( -file => 'my.ini' );

say $cfg->val('section', 'foo');

$cfg->setval('section', 'foo', 'baz');

say $cfg->val('section', 'foo');

$cfg->WriteConfig('my.ini');

$ ./changeini 
bar
baz

$ cat my.ini
[section]
name=dave
foo=baz

[another section]
stuff=random
```

If you're getting different results, then please let us know what you're doing differently.

Comment: I am using similar approach as shown in the code snippet above

Comment: So what different behaviour are you seeing? Please be precise.